# Arduino: Serial.readBytes() receiving wrong data after 30-60 minutes of program running

Tags: arrays, serial-port, arduino, rgb

I'm writing an Arduino program that is receiving via serial and array of RGB color data (sent as bytes) that it is used to update an LED strand. My system works great for about 30-60 minutes, until I start seeing obvious glitches in the color data, e.g., there shouldn't be any green showing up in the LED strand and I start seeing green. Here's the code Arduino side:

```
void loop() { 
 if (Serial.available() > 0) {
   if (Serial.peek() == '#') {
     Serial.read();
     read_mac();
     print_mac();
   } else {
     Serial.readBytes(in_data, 3*TOTAL_LEDS);
     for (int i = 0; i < 3 * TOTAL_LEDS; i+=3) {
       leds[i/3].setRGB(in_data[i], in_data[i+1], in_data[i+2]);
     }
   }
 }
 FastLED.show();
}
```

I've checked the state of the array right before writing to serial and everything looks fine. So, it must be something Arduino side.

The first part of the code is used by the system at startup to get the Arduino's MAC address. Is there anything blatantly silly about how I am receiving the data that could cause the error I've described, e.g., should I be pausing or flushing at some point to ensure best practices?

UPDATE:
Using USB, not RS-232. Have tried adjusting the baud rate.

Thanks!

Comment: This code will only work if the sun is shining and you've got the wind in your back.  But when you don't startup at just the right time or a timeout trips then you are permanently out of sync.  Reliable communications requires a protocol, a good way to detect the start of a command and a good way to detect that you got all the bytes.  Start improving it by *not* ignoring the return value of readBytes().  And keep in mind that it can also be the PC that caused the problem.  It usually is..

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is that you assume that:

> Serial.readBytes(in_data, 3*TOTAL_LEDS);

always return 3*TOTAL_LEDS number of bytes. But it might not always be the case. 
Check number of bytes read by Serial.readBytes and loop until 3*TOTAL_LEDS bytes was really read.

Here I adjusted your code:

```
 ..........
 } else {
   byte total_read = 0 ;
   byte *in_data_prt = in_data ;
   while ( total_read < (3 * TOTAL_LEDS) ) {
     byte read = Serial.readBytes(in_data_prt, (3 * TOTAL_LEDS) - total_read) ;
     in_data_prt += read ;
     total_read += read ;       
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < 3 * TOTAL_LEDS; i+=3) {
   ........
```

Hope it helps,

Michal